# Deploy Angular 2 app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, node.js, heroku, angular

In the past I always bundled my Angular 1 and Rails apps together and typically used heroku, which has worked great for me.  Now that I'm over to Angular 2 I want to separate out my Angular and Rails code.  I've created a very basic Angular 2 app via the Angular-Cli, but I haven't been able to figure out how to deploy it to Heroku.  I'm not using expressjs or anything like that.  Anyone figure it out yet?

Comment: I think the problem you're having is discussed in this thread. If you don't have a Heroku-supported backend then possibly you can't deploy it on its own. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/326

Comment: Yup you are right.  I actually just came up with a solution by using a vary basic PHP backend.  Thought it's not 100% smooth.  I'm going to post the answer and I'm hoping someone can help me figure out how the to get Angular-Cli to move a .php file and Procfile from scr to dist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I came up with a solution.  I had to add a very basic PHP backend, but it's pretty harmless.  Below is my process.

First setup a heroku app and Angular 2 app.

1. Create your heroku app
2. Set the heroku buildpack to heroku/php

   - `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php --app heroku-app-name`
3. Create a project via Angular-Cli
4. Add a index.php file to `/scr` with the below snippet

   `<?php include_once("index.html"); ?>`
5. Add a Procfile to `/scr` with the below snippet

   `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2`
6. Added `/deploy` to the .gitignore

Now I used a npm package to push a tarballs to heroku

1. Here's a simple package to upload the tarball, https://www.npmjs.com/package/heroku-deploy-tarball

   - `npm i heroku-deploy-tarball --save`
2. I'm also using tar.gz to create the tarball

   - `npm i tar.gz --save`
3. Then I created the `deploy.js` file at the root of my projecdt with the following code.  I first run the buildCommand specified and then move the index.php and Profile to the dist folder.  I then tarball the entire dist folder and it gets uploaded to heroku.

---

```
var deploy = require('heroku-deploy-tarball');
var targz = require('tar.gz');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var requestedTarget = process.argv[2];

if (!requestedTarget) {
  console.log('You must specify a deploy target');
  return;
}

var targets = {
  production: {
    app: 'heroku-app-name',
    tarball: 'deploy/build.tar.gz',
    buildCommand: 'ng build --prod'
  }
}

var moveCompressFiles = function (callback) {
  exec('cp ./src/index.php ./dist/index.php',
    function(err) {
      if(err)
        console.log(err);
      console.log('index.php was copied.');
    });
  exec('cp ./src/Procfile ./dist/Procfile',
    function(err) {
      if(err)
        console.log(err);
      console.log('Procfile was copied.');
    });

  new targz().compress('./dist', './deploy/build.tar.gz',
    function(err){
      if(err)
        console.log(err);
      else
        callback();
      console.log('The compression has ended!');
    });
};

console.log('Starting ' + targets[requestedTarget].buildCommand);
exec(targets[requestedTarget].buildCommand, {maxBuffer: 1024 * 500}, function(error) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(targets[requestedTarget].buildCommand + ' successful!');
    moveCompressFiles(function () {
      deploy(targets[requestedTarget]);
    });
  } else {
    console.log(targets[requestedTarget].buildCommand + ' failed.', error);
  }
});
```

4. Now just run `node deploy production` and it should deploy to heroku.

---

### Edit

Just got word from heroku that they are working on an experimental buildpack that would allow for static sites like this.  [Here is the link to the build pack.](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static)